# Change Back And Forth UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Hi I’m trying to get an image to change on a method call and if the method is recalled the original image comes back

```
-(void)change
{
if ((player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"]))
{
player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"]));
}
else
{
player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"]));
}
}
```

This works change the "first.png" image to "second.png" but when called again it doesn’t.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: No semi-colons (;)?  And what is with all the ')'s?  No way that code compiles.

Comment: my typing error there in there on the code

Comment: If you need help with code that isn't working then post the actual code. Details matter.

Comment: The `=` is the assignment operator. You need `==` for equality. But keep in mind that you should rarely use `==` with object pointers. The code you posted won't work properly in all cases using `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Dautermann, the way you're comparing two UIImages is wrong. Can't you simply keep an NSString property that tells you the image you're showing?

```
 -(void)change
 {
     if ([self.displayedImageTitle isEqualToString:@"first.png"]){
        player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"]));
        self.displayedImageTitle = @"second.png";
     }
     else{
        player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"]));
        self.displayedImageTitle = @"first.png";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you're making an invalid assumption that "`[UIImage imageNamed: @"first.png"]`" will always be the same UIImage object when you do a comparison. That isn't true. Every time you call the "`imageNamed`" API, you may be creating a brand new UIImage object.

Now, since UIImage object doesn't know anything about file names or image titles, you need to keep track of which image is being displayed and then toggle on *that*.

I'd suggest creating a subclassed UIImage object that has a filename or title property (that you would also need to set), ***or*** have your two UIImages as properties or ivars loaded into memory (that is, if these aren't giant memory hogging images) and then do your toggling.

Comment: Note the use of `=` instead of `==`. Your answer is valid but the code isn't even doing a proper comparison.